# IR2110 driven mosfet H-bridge not working properly

Tags: inverter, mosfet-driver

I am using this below H-bridge circuit for wireless power transfer. As seen it uses 555 to generate square wave of 50% duty cycle and adjusted to generate frequency of 140 kHz. Clearly, Driver1's Hin pin in connected to Driver2's Lin pin and vice versa. Let's assume these two junctions are **J1=D1_Hin+D2_Lin**, and **J2=D2_Hin+D1_Lin**. If I connect 555 output pin (3) to either J1 or J2 the load (a dc motor) is driven fine with expected behavior, i.e., if J1 is connected to Pin 3 of 555 the motor runs clockwise, and when J2 is connected to Pin 3 of 555 it runs anti-clockwise. Now in the final circuit (see schematic) J1 is connected to pin 3 of 555, and inverted output from CD4049DE (pin 2) is connected to J2. When J1 goes high, J2 should go low, and vice versa causing the oscillation to happen across the load. Ideally at this state the motor should just vibrate and should not run to any direction, or if I connect a LC circuit as load, oscillation would occur in the coil, which is the actual purpose of this circuit. 
Now the problem is output 3 of 555 can drive the circuit via J1 or J2, but when I use the inverted output from the inverted chip, it can't drive any side of the mosfet driver.

[image: schematic].
[image]
I don't presently have oscilloscope to measure peak to peak voltages of the oscillation but multimeter shows 2.5 at pin 3 of 555, and 1.5 volt at inverter output. The inverter chip is CD4049BE. I think pp voltage would be little bit high, but anyway it seems inverter output would be around 2-3 volt, so ir2110 won't be driven as it needs >3v ([got information from here](https://tahmidmc.blogspot.com/2013/01/using-high-low-side-driver-ir2110-with.html)).

Why this is happening?

*EDIT*
Scope output:
The original circuit gave me 70%-30% duty cycle, never 50-50.
[image]
Then I found that setting a Vcc/2 control voltage can give [~50% duty cycle](https://www.multisim.com/content/WCwZ5PA8h9FZZStdE75ibY/555-50-duty-cycle-astable-multivibrator-control-voltage-set-to-05vcc/).
[image]

input vs Output plot

Driving via J1 means 555 output is connected to J1.
[image]

inverter output connected to J1:

[image]
Clearly it looks like while taking the output from inverter output the mosfets are not driven properly. It looks like though the voltage output is sufficient the current is insufficient. I will take output from 3 inverter in parallel to see if things get improved or not. Also I will try with original 74HC4049.

Comment: *While I am using the out put directly from 555 and providing it to ir2110 HIn, an LIn pins the mosfets are driven properly* If you provide the same signal to HIn and LIn, you will blow Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4. I wonder if you tried this. If not, could you please rewrite the quoted sentence so it becomes more clear (correcting the spelling and location of the comma, etc)

Comment: pot contrlos duty cycle and Vdc avg. they should go close to rails which all could be 12V rather than 5V

Comment: how do you know what is the output of the inverter?

Comment: @Tony Stewart - I did not understand you. I added a pic of my design, could you please take a look at that and suggest accordingly?

Comment: @Tony Stewart - For this astable multivibrator the duty cycle is always 50%. I found it from https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555_oscillator.html. And are you saying to supply the 555 with 12v instead of 5v in that case output would go to ~10v, and also power the inverter up with 12v instead of 5v?

Comment: The inputs use Schmitt triggers but CD4049DE has poor RdsOn @ 5V compared to 12V so slower rise time.  but you can also improve rise time with lower RdsOn = Vol/Iol using 74HC4049 @5V.. this improves dead time and heat rise of driver.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Are you saying if I use 74HC4049 instead of CD4049DE, the rise time issue would be resolved? Ok, so let me try with 74HC4049.

Comment: There may be other problems with wiring (ringing) and Vdd ripple (lack of low ESR ceramic caps across IC's) or shared ground shift noise   But 74HC have lower drive R vs CD4xxx @ 5V

Comment: The input is supplied via a li-ion battery boosted to 12 v using mt3068 dc-dc boost converter module, that means the ripple is already high on the output, but I already added 100 nf ceramic cap across vdd (Pin-1) and gnd (Pin-8), not exactly across though (see the pic, in between the inverter chip and pot). When you say low esr ceramic what do you exactly mean? Can you suggest any specific type/value cap, and should it be kept closest, i mean the other pin of the cap should be adjacent to pin 8? Sorry I don't have that much electronic background.

Comment: Is there any possibility to use any IGBT (say Mje13003) based switching to replace the inverter chip?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Would you please put your thoughts on the above concerns?

Comment: get a scope, even a free software scope and make some valid measurments

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I have attached the scope output. Please see. I am currently testing the oscillator on bread board. Please see the rise/fall times. Do you think these values are source of the problem?

Comment: Your next question should be . How Do I design PWM now that I have 50% d.c.  Answer: THR voltage is 1/3 to 2/3 of Vcc so you need to apply DC bias 0 to Vx to adjust that bias with choice of R values. and DAC voltage  maybe

Comment: You can use top one for direction control and bottom one for PWM acceleration control. or use joystick carefully with centre brake stop position. and no coasting or have motor coast control switch and brake switch by design changes

Comment: Choose to control PWM with CTRL V from near 0 to Vcc

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I did not understand a bit from your last two comments, forgive my noobness. If you see the second scope image, i could achieve 50% duty cycle by putting a 10K across pin 5 and gnd. The channel 2 output is the output of cd4049 inverter. As you can see the peak to peak is 4.39v that is sufficient to trigger mosfet drivers. I am asking if the rise/fall time 104ns and 140ns respectively are not fast enough to drive the mosfet drivers.

Comment: No It is not. rise fall times must be matched within 10ns +/-10 or not use it as you have. Instead, PWM only LO input and use HI as direction control and same for both IC's except HI inverted. GO READ how full bridge Motor controllers work until understood before you try to design it .Failure may cause SHoot thru with drivers shorting out Vcc (poof)  > Only minor modifications are needed. but go understand 1st

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thanks a lot for your valuable comment. Now let me tell you the purpose of this circuit. Though I used this with a motor as a load, I actually intend to design a wireless power transmitter that requires alternating the direction of current flow on every half of the signal, so that alternating current passes through the resonant LC circuit. So I need this 50% duty cycle alternating current for creating resonance in the parallel LC tank.

Comment: It is critical to define symmetry of input, output RdsOn, , deadtime and therefore Zout= RdsOn/(1-%deadtime) and Q= X(f)/Z so you understand Q right?  With slow sloppy risetimes you cannot control Symmetry. Lower Driver logic impedance is needed perhaps 74LVC or HC or a better IC.

Comment: _"it seems inverter output would be around 2-3 volt, so ir2110 won't be driven as it needs >3v"_ - If I am reading the scope trace correctly, inverter high output is ~4.6V, which should be plenty. Do you have 10x probes? If set to 1x the scope will have high capacitive loading, making transition times look slower. Your CD4049BE appears to be a 'fake'. I suspect it is actually a relabeled CD4049UBE. Even so it seems to be working OK, but you could parallel buffers to provide more drive strength if needed.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 From your comment what I understand is I need a chip with faster rise/fall time that you mentioned earlier - 74HC4049. I will find and use and let you know how it goes. Besides what do you think about using IGBT (MJE10003) as an inverter?

Comment: rise time and skew are critical in PWM motor controllers to have guaranteed dead time

Comment: @BruceAbbott The idea of parallel drive is really fascinating, parallel drive would definitely increase the drive current. I will check if that improves things. How much current do you think is required to drive the mosfet drivers? I will check with 10x probes as well. Regarding the chip - I am planning to buy 74HC4049.

Comment: Your latest scope trace of "inverter output connected to J1:" is disturbing. It looks like feedback from the output of the IR2110 to the input. Can you show us the waveform on each side of the bridge output?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I add a dc motor as the load and added a scope probe to one of the load input lead. Is this a correct way to measure? When you ask waveform on each side of the bridge, do want mean to disconnect the load and then use the scope probe on each output lines? Couple of more things: if you see the other waveform the peak-to-peak voltage is ~7v, why it is not ~12v? And I just discovered one of the ir2110s is getting more hot that the other in no-load condition. With load both are almost equally hot (i mean mild) that might be expected. Do you think the one that is getting hot is fried?

Comment: _"I add a dc motor as the load and added a scope probe to one of the load input lead. Is this a correct way to measure?"_ - No, it isn't. The test load should be close to what you intend to use (represented by L1 and C7, right?), and you should tell us exactly what it is. How can we diagnose your problem with such an unknown? At least now I know where the 300kHz oscillation came from!  Swap the IR2110s, does the heat follow the chip? If not then it's the circuit that causes one to heat more. I don't see any waveforms with 7V, did you post them?